# Any way not to have to log into network on restart when using a live image?

Tags: networking, live-usb

I am not network savvy but each time I power the laptop with Ubuntu running from a flash drive or disk I need to manually connect to my network. Any way to have it auto-connect please?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You need to [edit] the question to add more details. To start, have you installed Ubuntu or are you running a live image? What version? What sort of network is it -- Wifi, VPN, LAN, mobile? Have you already checked if the network settings have an auto-connect setting?

Comment: Sorry. Running a live image, I have created a bootable usb with ubuntu. I cannot install Ubuntu because the HDD has failed. Version is 16.04.3 Wifi network. I don't see an auto-connect in settings.

Comment: OK - live image - that's probably the root of the problem. Did you enable persistence while making it? Please [edit] the question to add details.

Comment: I can't remember seeing an option titled "persistence" when creating the usb. I simply followed the instructions from this resource: 
  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the [edit] button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: You can use your Live flash drive to do a Full install to USB, this is more stable than a persistent install. The Full install USB will allow you to save data and settings from boot to boot

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a live image without persistence (per [comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100907/any-way-not-to-have-to-log-into-network-on-restart/1100936#comment1814487_1100907)), there is no way to do this. A live image forgets all settings as soon as you turn it off.

You could look into [making a persistent live image](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/) (which Rufus doesn't support) or even a [full install on the flash drive](https://askubuntu.com/q/16988/301745).